# bind to selected interfaces

Tags: c, linux, sockets, network-programming

My application bind to all interfaces using "sockaddr_ll.sll_ifindex = 0". What I want is either to bind socket to selected interfaces (e.g. eth0, eth1, eth4) or bind to all interfaces but except loopback.
The first solution to create several sockets is really hard for me because I use ring buffer. I was trying to find some solution but with no luck so far.
Any advice is welcome.

Comment: First, post your code.  Second, `bind()` takes as its arguments a socket file descriptor, an address, and a length.  Thus, you `bind()` a socket to one *address*, which includes any address.  See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html

Comment: Why do you want to disable the loopback device?

Comment: I want to disable loopback because I have a lot of traffic on loopback and I'm encountering packet drops.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: I want to gater traffic from all addresses but only specific interfaces. You can select one interface when using sockaddr_ll as addess.

Comment: Although I think my answer will do what was asked, I have some doubts that this will solve the packet drop issue. In fact, it seems odd there is a "lot" of traffic on loopback at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no easy way to do exactly what you want. A couple options:

1. Open multiple sockets and use select() and recv()/recvfrom()/read()/etc. to receive from multiple fds in the same place you would use recv() by itself. This is the direct solution, it is verbose but can be made functionally equivalent to reading from a single socket. It would be more appropriate for production maintainable code.
2. A sneaky trick that may work for you: You can open one socket and bind to the same port and the loopback address 127.0.0.1 or the loopback interface. Then open a second socket to the same port bound to 0.0.0.0 INADDR_ANY. Then you ignore the first socket - it will capture any packets coming in on the loopback interface because it is a more specific binding. Packets coming in from anywhere else will end up on the second socket.

You need to use the SO_REUSEADDR option to allow this, and I would set the first sockets receive buffer to a small value. If using TCP you will have to at least listen() on the first socket.

Comment: Thanks for advice I have implemented the first one already but will try the second one as well, even if only for fun ;)